# Pivot Table to Display Multiple Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have an Items Table that contains information about the Item. I have a ShipDate that is linked to my Item table by a foreign key (ItemID). If I had the two tables with the following data:

Items Table:

> ```
> ID    Item Description        Cost 
> 1          Apples             $15
> ```

ShipDate Table:

> ```
> ItemID          DATE
> 1              06/15/14 
> 1              06/20/14 
> 1              07/01/14
> ```

I would like to use a pivot to output:

> ```
> ItemDesription    Cost          ShipDate       ShipDate        ShipDate
> Apples            $15           06/15/14       06/20/14        07/01/14
> ```

I tried creating a join but it does not have the correct output since it repeats the Item:

> ```
> ItemDesription    Cost          ShipDate       
>  Apples            $15            06/15/14       
>  Apples            $15            06/20/14            
>  Apples            $15            07/01/14
> ```

Here's my join:

```
SELECT *
FROM ItemTable
Left Outer Join ShipDateTable
on ItemTable.Id= ShipDateTable.ItemID
```

Comment: What platform are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL?

Comment: For mySQL -> http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

Comment: Please also show us your attempts at a solution.

Comment: Most SQL databases won't be entirely happy with generating multiple columns with the same name - since in SQL, generally, columns should be referred to be name, not by ordinal position.

Comment: I've added some edits to my question. Hopefully it will make it more clear.  Good point @Damien_The_Unbeliever about the columns... i wonder what I should do to get around that.

Comment: @user3281388 - well, one recommendation - especially if the number of columns to generate isn't fixed at 3 - would be to consider performing the pivot at a different level than the database - I assume the result set you're generating isn't going directly to the user but is being processed by some other piece of code?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for your recommendation. That's definitely something I need to think about. I am uploading the tables I have in SQL to an ASP.NET tablegrid. So I could alter the column names in there. Thanks!